# How to Use hypertext in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need to create a underlined label  in a form using wxWidgets. When user clicks on that label I have to execute 1 function. Can we create such hypertext in wxwidgets? Now I am using a button for this, when user clicks on button some event is triggered. But instead of button underlined label will look too good.

Answer (score 0):

@aromahola,

Look up wxHyperLink in the wx documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The class you want is [wxHyperLinkCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.1/classwx_hyperlink_ctrl.html).

Comment: `wxHyperLinkCtrl` is a native control, so it's supposed to look like all the other controls on the system, not as whatever you need. If you really require totally custom appearance, you can use `wxHtmlWindow` instead or maybe you can just use markup support in `wxGenericStaticText`.